# Agregar contador en pagina secundaria y principal tambien

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Estoy haciendo una pagina web(sitio de ventas) con base de datos incluida(sql) estoy usando html, css, js y php.
Programando el carrito consegui con ayuda de la cominidad hacer que el contador de la cantidad de producto se mostrara,pero me surgio otro problema.
en mi pagina yo cuente con dos seciones de la misma **index.php**(es donde se encuentran todos los productos en venta) y **details.php**(en esta es donde se encuentra la informacion de un solo producto en espesifico al cliquear).
Ambas seciones tienen un boton de compra, ahora , el problema que me esta precentando el carrito es que este contador solo se muestra y agrega en la pagina **details.php**
mientas que en la pagina principal no hace nada, y segundo que al regresar de la pagina details a la index, no regresa mostrando los valores.
Aclarar que son enlaces directos en el mismo proyecto no por links distintos.
pense que poniendo esto en el codigo ayudaria

```
$num_cart //es la variable que contrala el contador en el carrito, es decir la que lo muestra = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos'])){
    $num_cart=count($_SESSION['carrito']['producto']);
}
```

esta la otra parte del codigo

**Funcion JS**

```
function addProducto(id, token) {
            let url = 'clases/carrito.php'
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('id', id)
            formData.append('token', token)

            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                mode: 'cors'               
            }).then(response => response.json())
                .then(datos => {

                    if (datos.ok) {

                        let elemento = document.getElementById("contador-productos")
                        elemento.innerHTML = datos.numero

                    }
                })               
        }
```

esta en ambas paginas

**Carrito.php** // es donde se configura el contador y tal

```
<?php
require '../config/config.php';

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $token = $_POST['token'];

  $token_tmp = hash_hmac('sha1', $id, KEY_TOKEN);

  if ($token == $token_tmp) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id])) {
      $_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id] += 1;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id] = 1;
    }

    $datos['numero'] = count($_SESSION['carrito']['producto']);
    $datos['ok'] = true;
  } else {
    $datos['ok'] = false;
  }
} else {
  $datos['ok'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($datos);
```

esta tambien en las dos paginas agregadas

**y este es la configuracion de la porcion donde se muestra el contador**

```
<span id="contador-productos">
 <?php echo $num_cart; ?>
</span>
```

Gracias de antemanos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces es subir el valor de ese campo: $_SESSION['carrito']['producto']
[$id]
Por lo que realmente sería esto para el valor de tu contador:

```
$num_cart=$_SESSION['carrito']['producto'][$id];
```

Si en un lugar de tu página ejecutas esto, lo verás más claro:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```